# Laravel take out first result from collections

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the following method in a controller

```
public function artikel(){
        $breadcrumb = array(
            'Home' => URL::to('/'),
            'Artikel' => ''
        );

        $this->layout->title = "Egoji";
        $artikels = Posting::orderBy("created_at","desc")->where("postings.tipe","=","artikel")->paginate(5);

        $this->layout->content = View::make("frontend.artikel.index",array("artikels"=>$artikels, 'breadcrumb'=>$breadcrumb))->render();

}
```

in the view `frontend.artikel.index` i am trying to takeout first artikel using `$artikels->shift()`. i get the first artikel, but it doesnt remove from the collection, it still there when i loop the rest.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you are using `array_shift`?